# Windows 7 is not showing 2 other hard drives

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

Windows 7 is installed on one physical disk, and the other two disks (one seagate, and the other Western Digital) are not detected as existing in the OS. The other two disks are meant as storage disks, and not as multiple operating systems. Is there a way I can force Windows 7 to acknowledge their existance?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I would do is check if the disks are showing under windows *Disk Management*.

Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Computer Management

Under the *Storage* option in the left hand list will be *Disk Management*.  You should see entries for each disk drive.

[image]

It is possible the disks are not formatted.  If that is the case, the disks will not show as drives in Windows Explorer.

I've also seen a disk be assigned a drive letter that conflicts with mapped network drives.  The network drives have always won that conflict.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. I got up and left the computer, and when I returned (12 hours later, and one reboot later) it suddenly recognized all the drives...weird. I wanted to thank you though for taking the time to answer my question because I was seriously ready to cry after I had put so much effort into building my rig only to be put off by a software glitch. Would you happen to have any idea as to what happened to it?